# Understanding glDrawElements internal behavior with Vertex Arrays

Tags: opengl

I am trying to understand how glDrawElements knows the range of elements to be sent to the GPU when using vertex arrays, because the glVertexPointer or glColorPointer do not have information about the number of elements as VBOs have.

OpenGL specification does not say anything about it so I assume the behavior depends on the driver implementation of the function, but I can only think of a solution, in which the driver needs to do a complete pass over all indices to calculate the limits before doing the transfer to graphics memory.

If that is correct then the performance of glDrawElements should be a lot worse than glDrawRangeElements which already knows the limits, but the information I have found in some sites seems to counteract this assumption.

Anyone knows some specific details about how this internally works?

Comment: If every `glDrawElements` call would transfer the vertex data before rendering, your application would be incredible slow.

Comment: @dari: Actually, that is effectively how vertex processing worked prior to VBOs. When the vertex data was stored in client-owned memory it had to be copied or `glDrawElements (...)` had to block until the draw operation completed to prevent client-side modification since the client/server run asynchronously. So Vertex Array Ranges (DMA data transfer) schemes were created to speed up vertex data pulling, but ultimately the solution was to use server-managed memory (buffer objects) to store vertex data instead.

Comment: @dari: In fact the peripheral bus bandwidth used to be a very limiting bottleneck. Because of that already the NVidia GeForce 2 (made in the previous millenium) had an OpenGL extension (very cumbersome to use) to place vertex data in graphics memory. These days with PCI-E being able to shovel up to 10GiB/s between the GPU and the system RAM, and GPUs having their own MMU things are not so bad anymore. Client side vertex arrays perform very well. Today the limiting factor is texture access bandwidth.

Comment: @dari: In fact today an implementation may decide to keep VBOs entirely in system RAM, if the usage pattern statistics hint, that the limiting factor is texture bandwidth and not vertex attribute throughput.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me you are using bad docs to learn:
glVertexPointer and glColorPointer should not be used any more, rather go for

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray();
glVertexAttribPointer();
```

But you're completely right: nothing in those calls can tell which range of data will be needed.  The range of VBO (or GL_ARRAY_BUFFER) elements needed comes out of inspecting the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

Well, and as this might be cumbersome to a driver IMHO if you set data to a VBO, all will be transferred to Video RAM immediately.  Same goes with the IBO.  So with enough GPU memory, all data will already be there, the GPU gets only a transfer of the arguments given to glDrawElements.

So your assumption on glDrawRangeElements is right, but this call will only be a different call than glDrawElements on limited-capacity-devices or when you maxed out the video memory.

Anything else depends on the implementation specifics of the driver.  Most likely it's fastest to transfer the whole VBO and IBO again (erasing other data from gpu ram, which is unnecessary at that moment), if memory was low and the data was erased prior to your call to glDrawElements.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know that depending of the hints of glBufferData the driver can decide to update immediately the buffer to GPU but I'm asking of the performance without using VBOs. This makes me think also if VBOs have any advantage over Vertex Arrays when you put the data and only draws once, for example with a huge array of points where you need to draw it in chunks because they don't fit in video memory.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  The usecase you state really creates a situation where VBOs make no sense.  As I understand current OpenGL, not using VBOs is deprecated.  So you should most likely update buffers often, and they should be declared as GL_STREAM_DRAW.  Assuming you mean VAOs with Vertex Arrays: they still are good: they store bound buffers and Vertex Attribute Settings.  If you modify your VBOs (i.e. GL_ARRAY_BUFFER) and make sure the vertex attribute settings don't change, you can still reuse the same VAO over and over.  But it doesn't answer your question, I'm afraid.